# How do I customize WooCommerce products query globally at once?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to query the products by locations that are a `product attribute` in WooCommerce. I want to apply this query throughout the website including archives. I tried to use `woocommerce_product_query` but no luck. Please help me achieve my requirements.

```
function g_filter_products_by_location( $q ){
    $tax_query = $q->get( 'tax_query' );
    $tax_query[] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_locations',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'location1' )
        )
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'g_filter_products_by_location' );
```

Comment: If you do a tax query like this on the archive page, you're only filtering for variations, which shouldn't be showing on the archive anyway... right?

Comment: If there is a `location2` in the variation the product should not display on archive pages.

Comment: I think there's no need to filter on the archive page.

Comment: What you have... when i try it - it is working.  Only products that have 'location1' will show up.  Anything else will not show up in archive pages, including shop page.

Comment: That's weird, it's not working on mine. I have `WooCommerce 4.0.1`, what version of `woo` do you have?

Comment: Same. You should verify your locations settings and confirm the slugs in use.